# Confused about calling default, no arg constructor

Tags: java

From Bates and Sierra:

```
class Top {
    public Top(String s) {
        System.out.print("B");
    }
}

public class Bottom2 extends Top {
    public Bottom2(String s) {
        System.out.print("D");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Bottom2("C");
        System.out.println(" ");
    }
}
```

The choices are:

A. BD

B. DB

C. BDC

D. DBC

E. Compilation fails

Answer:

® ✓ E is correct. The implied super() call in Bottom2’s constructor cannot be satisfied because there isn’t a no-arg constructor in Top. A default, no-arg constructor is generated by the compiler only if the class has no constructor defined explicitly.

But I'm confused. Isn’t “public Top(String s) { System.out.print("B"); } ” a constructor defined explicitly? Where am I going wrong?

I've seen this question here but didn't really understand the answers.

Answer (score 2):

The implicit call tries to call `super` with no parameters. `Top` does not have a no-arg constructor, so the call to `super` is trying to call a method that doesn't exist. When you want to call a non no-arg constructor, you need to do it explicitly. `Bottom2`'s constructor should call `super(s)` to call `Top`'s 1-arg constructor.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this constructor is *defined* in the base class. But you also have to *call* it from the sub class.

In every sub-class constructor, you must call a base-class constructor.  The only exception is if there is a base-class constructor without arguments.  This constructor is called by default.

That means your code should look like this:

```
public Bottom2(String s) {
    super(s);
    // ...
}
```

As an alternative, you could add a `Top()` constructor the the base class.

Comment: "But you also have to call it from the sub class."                                                                                                                                      That's where I've been going wrong. Solved with one sentence!!! Great! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you write your own constructor which is parameterized, it replaces the default constructor provided by Java **unless** you define the no-arg constructor by yourself again.

Now, in `Top`, there is a parameterized constructor and the default no-arg constructor is gone unless you explicitly define one. Hence, just calling `super()` won't work. You need to pass in a `String` argument and call `super(string)`.

Try writing a default constructor for `Top` and then call `super()` in the `Bottom` class. It won't flash that error =)

Try this:

```
class Top {
    public Top() { System.out.println("No-arg constructor in Top"); }
    public Top(String s) {
        System.out.print("B");
    }
}

public class Bottom2 extends Top {
    public Bottom2(String s) {
        System.out.print("D");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Bottom2("C");
        System.out.println(" ");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> But I'm confused. Isn’t “public Top(String s) { System.out.print("B");
>   } ” a constructor defined explicitly? Where am I going wrong?

public Top(String s) is a constructor defined explicitly. As the correct answer said, A default no-arg constructor is generated by the compiler **only if the class has no constructor defined explicitly**

Answer (score 0):

Solution
1.you are creating object of base class that is new Bottom2() and passing argument as string that is "C" then as per the calling, call get to the Bottom2(String s) constructor and print "D".

2.at same time Bottom2() extends Top class so "B" need to print but Top(String s) constructor having string as parameter and in main class there is no parameter passing to Top(String s) constructor.

3.that why compiler give us an error

4.below giving solution over this problem

```
    class Top {
    public Top() {
        System.out.println("B");
    }
}
public class Bottom2 extends Top {
    public Bottom2(String s) {
        System.out.println("D");
    }
public static void main(String args[]) {
        new Bottom2("C");
        System.out.println(" ");
    }
}
```